# batch.Download.ImageCollection.toAsset and pyramidingPolicy

Tags: google-earth-engine

I added pyramidingPolicy into the batch function. However, it still uses
the median pyramidingPolicy. Something on the core batch process function must be needed/added?

```
batch.Download.ImageCollection.toAsset(rgb, 'to_TIMEMACHINE2_simple', 
             {
             scale: 30, 
             region:region,
             type: 'float',
             pyramidingPolicy: {'.default': 'mode'}
             })
```

Comment: are you using `geetools`?

Comment: Thanks, Rodrigo. Yes, I am using your functions!

Comment: are you in the code editor or using the Python API?

Comment: I am using the code editor!

Answer (score 0):

Earth Engine didn't properly support pyramidingPolicy for asset exports until about a year ago